# How to handle "Pooled connection observed an error" in Spring Webflux?

Tags: spring, proxy, request, spring-webflux

I am using Webflux to make a `Flux` of concurrent requests via proxy to a web server.  Depending on the proxy, sometimes the connection fails.  I would like to catch these errors and handle them (ideally by returning an empty `Mono` object)

```
2019-02-17 16:48:19.947 ERROR 32265 --- [or-http-epoll-8] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0xf7c8834b, L:/192.168.2.247:45536 - R:101.248.64.72/101.248.64.72:80] Pooled connection observed an error

io.netty.handler.proxy.ProxyConnectException: http, none, /101.248.64.72:80 => domain.com:443, io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: syscall:read(..) failed: Connection reset by peer
at io.netty.handler.proxy.ProxyHandler.setConnectFailure(ProxyHandler.java:344) [netty-handler-proxy-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.handler.proxy.ProxyHandler.exceptionCaught(ProxyHandler.java:246) [netty-handler-proxy-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
```

These messages are very long and make the log unreadable later on if debugging is required.  I've tried catching it in line with the request code by using `.onErrorResume(err -> Mono.empty())` but it doesn't seem to prevent the error logs.

Below is my code:

```
return proxiedWebClient
    .get()
    .uri(uri)
    .exchange()
    .flatMap(clientResponse -> clientResponse.toEntity(String.class))
    .onErrorResume(error -> Mono.empty());
```

The expected result is that connection errors are simply dropped and not added into the `Flux` when `Flux.merge` is subsequently called.